# FLEX: can I set labels visibility?

Tags: apache-flex, label

Can I set label visibility in Flex ?

```
newUser = new LinkButton();
newUser.label = "hello";
newUser.labelPlacement = ButtonLabelPlacement.BOTTOM;
newUser.label. //visibility ?
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can just toggle the visibility of the label in the LinkButton.  Here are some options you can try alternatively.

1. Toggle the visibility of the LinkButton, `newUser.visible = true;`
2. Build a custom component that works like a LinkButton but allows you to toggle the label visibility.

Comment: ok I will go for the custom component. It probably doesn't make sense to use LinkButton for this.